# Struts2 validations issue

Tags: java, jsp, validation, struts2, themes

I am trying to validate a form using the Struts2 validations annotation but it does not seem to work and does not show required mark on the labels.
Here is my code:

**`login.jsp`:**

```xml
 <s:form  action="/Login"  validate = "true">    
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><s:label theme=”simple” required="true">Username :</s:label></td>
    <td><s:textfield name="userName" theme=”simple” /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><s:label theme=”simple” required="true">Password :</s:label></td>
    <td><s:textfield name="password" theme=”simple” /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><s:submit  value="Login" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</s:form>
```

**`LoginAction.java`:**

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {
    private String userName;
    private String password;
        
    @Validations(requiredStrings={@RequiredStringValidator(type=ValidatorType.FIELD, message="User Name can ot be empty.", fieldName="userName")})
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
        
    @Validations(requiredStrings={@RequiredStringValidator(type=ValidatorType.FIELD, message="Password can ot be empty.", fieldName="password" )})
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    public String execute()
    {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<struts>
    <package name="demo" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="*" class="mypkg.action.{0}Action">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Can somebody help and notice if there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: `<action name="*" class="mypkg.action.{0}Action">` please try and make sure you are doing it right.Please post stacktrace as well

Comment: I used the same. This is the question only that is not working.

Comment: <s:head/> is missing I guess.

Comment: i have added <s:head/>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Validations` annotation then you should place it on action method. Validator annotations are placed on the *setter* methods. Also you are using `validate = "true"` which means the client-side validation. Make sure you have javascript (with the help of `<s:head/>`) and themes like `xhtml` or `css_xhtml` applyed  to the form to make the validation errors visible. I.e. theme `simple` doesn't work here, remove it from fields.

> If you don’t specify a theme, then Struts 2 will use the xhtml theme
> by default.

Referrences:

- [Introduction to Struts2 themes](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/themes.html)
- [Client-side validation example](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/client-validation.html)
- [Validation examples](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation-annotation.html#ValidationAnnotation-Examples)
- [Head tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/dojo-head-tag.html)